# RESTful service contracts for protobuf definitions

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers, spring-cloud-contract

**Design Overview**

- Request and response objects are modelled in protobuf.
- Classes are generated in Python and Java using protoc.
- Users create request objects in Python and send it to RESTful Java Spring Boot microservices.
- A JavaScript React web application and Node server also invoke the RESTful endpoints.
- Requests and responses are serialized to Json.
- 1+ Java microservices may use the same request/response objects. eg. an aggregator/API gateway microservice will pass on the request to the actual microservice, providing the relevant service.

**Question**

Protobuf enforces some level of type checking, and a kind of contract, for request/response objects. However, how do I develop, maintain and enforce RESTful contracts (HTTP verb + path + request + response)?

**Is this the way to go?**

Develop contracts in [Spring Cloud Contract](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_proto/src/test/resources/contracts/beer/rest/shouldGrantABeerIfOldEnough.groovy) and auto-generate integration contract tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out a sample that uses protobuffers with spring cloud contract on the producer side here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_proto and on the consumer side here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/consumer_proto

The very idea is to treat the content as binary. Let's say that I stored the request and response in a binary format in a .bin file. Then I can create the following contract

````
package contracts.beer.rest


import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description("""
Represents a successful scenario of getting a beer
```
given:
    client is old enough
when:
    he applies for a beer
then:
    we'll grant him the beer
```
""")
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/check'
        body(fileAsBytes("PersonToCheck_old_enough.bin"))
        headers {
            contentType("application/x-protobuf")
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body(fileAsBytes("Response_old_enough.bin"))
        headers {
            contentType("application/x-protobuf")
        }
    }
}
````

Having such a controller

```
@RestController
public class ProducerController {

    private final PersonCheckingService personCheckingService;

    public ProducerController(PersonCheckingService personCheckingService) {
        this.personCheckingService = personCheckingService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check",
            method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes="application/x-protobuf",
            produces="application/x-protobuf")
    public Beer.Response check(@RequestBody Beer.PersonToCheck personToCheck) {
        //remove::start[]
        if (this.personCheckingService.shouldGetBeer(personToCheck)) {
            return Beer.Response.newBuilder().setStatus(Beer.Response.BeerCheckStatus.OK).build();
        }
        return Beer.Response.newBuilder().setStatus(Beer.Response.BeerCheckStatus.NOT_OK).build();
        //remove::end[return]
    }
    
}

interface PersonCheckingService {
    Boolean shouldGetBeer(Beer.PersonToCheck personToCheck);
}
```

and such a base class for the generated tests (I assume that you've setup the contract plugin)

```
package com.example;

//remove::start[]
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
//remove::end[]
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BeerRestBase.Config.class)
public abstract class BeerRestBase {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    //remove::start[]
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(this.context);
    }
    // remove::end[]

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Import({ ProtoConfiguration.class, ProducerController.class })
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        PersonCheckingService personCheckingService() {
            return argument -> argument.getAge() >= 20;
        }

    }

}
```

will result in proper test and stub generation. Check out the aforementioned sample for concrete implementation details.

On the consumer side you can fetch the stubs and run your tests against them

```
package com.example;

import org.assertj.core.api.BDDAssertions;
import org.junit.Assume;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.junit.StubRunnerRule;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

/**
 * @author Marcin Grzejszczak
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class ProtoTest {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    int port;

    @Rule
    public StubRunnerRule rule = new StubRunnerRule()
            .downloadStub("com.example", "beer-api-producer-proto")
            .stubsMode(StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL);

    @Before
    public void setupPort() {
        this.port = this.rule.findStubUrl("beer-api-producer-proto").getPort();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_give_me_a_beer_when_im_old_enough() throws Exception {
        Beer.Response response = this.restTemplate.postForObject(
                "http://localhost:" + this.port + "/check",
                Beer.PersonToCheck.newBuilder().setAge(23).build(), Beer.Response.class);

        BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(Beer.Response.BeerCheckStatus.OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_reject_a_beer_when_im_too_young() throws Exception {
        Beer.Response response = this.restTemplate.postForObject(
                "http://localhost:" + this.port + "/check",
                Beer.PersonToCheck.newBuilder().setAge(17).build(), Beer.Response.class);
        response = response == null ? Beer.Response.newBuilder().build() : response;

        BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(Beer.Response.BeerCheckStatus.NOT_OK);
    }
}
```

Again, please check the concrete sample for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Marcin!What do you think about using protobuf for modeling requests and responses? Our team doesn't have much experience with this tech stack, so I want to be careful about adding new things without adding much value.

Comment: If you don't have experience and this tech doesn't solve any problems for you just don't use it

Comment: The ability to generate code in Python and Java is an important requirement for us. We tried out Avro and Json Schema also, but Protobuf feels more natural in our use-case. Is this a standard approach?

Comment: There is no standard approach. You should use whatever serves you to solve your issues

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question because it represents a modern way to manage APIs using contracts with Protobuf.

I will talk more about the API management with Protobuf later, but straight to your question - when trying to define REST contract, you will need to use Openapi annotations and then generate Openapi definition file.

```
service UserService {
  rpc AddUser(AddUserRequest) returns (User) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      // Route to this method from POST requests to /api/v1/users
      post: "/api/v1/users"
      body: "*"
    };
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_operation) = {
      summary: "Add a user"
      description: "Add a user to the server."
      tags: "Users"
    };
  }
```

Generating OpenAPI definitions

```
protoc \
    -I "$PROTO_ROOT" \
    -I "$ROOT"/protos/thirdparty/grpc-gateway/ \
    -I "$ROOT"/protos/thirdparty/googleapis \
    --openapiv2_out="$ROOT/gen/swagger" \
    "$proto"
```

When trying to create a professional APIs management you should take the following steps:

- Create the services definition using Protobuf IDL language
- Generate Openapi definition files
- Generate HTTP clients from the Openapi definition
- generate Swagger UI client from your Openapi definition
- generate gRPC stub from Protobuf (if required gRPC support)
- Add back-compatibility checks on new changes
- Add style code checks to guarantee consistency

You can see everything mentioned above in this project https://github.com/apssouza22/modern-api-management